# Multidimension C program structure

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, gcc-warning

I have a program written in C, which is intended to operate as a multidimensional code. For example, the user can choose 1D or 2D by setting the MACRO "DIMENSION" to a "1" or a "2". Here is a simple example:

```
#define DIMENSION 1
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)

void fun(double *x, double *y);
int main()
{
  double *x;
  double *y;

  x = calloc(5,sizeof(double));
#if DIMENSION == 2
  y = calloc(5,sizeof(double));
#elif DIMENSION == 1
  UNUSED(y);
#endif

  fun(x,y);

  free(x);
#if DIMENSION == 2
  free(y);
#endif
  return 0;
}

fun(double *x, double *y)
{
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      x[i] = i;
#if DIMENSION == 2
      y[i] = i;
#endif
  }

}
```

Just to point out, I'm using GCC (not all my end users will be) and I do have the complier options -Wuninitialized and -Wmaybe-uninitialized on. I would like to suppress the warnings during the compilation process but still keep the check. I've read about using the following:

```
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)
```

It seems to suppress some of the warnings but not all. Is this because the function "fun" takes the y-term even though I don't initialize it? How would I fix this? Ideally, by setting "DIMENSION" to "1" the code will compile without warning as a 1D code and not require the memory overhead. Suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#define DIMENSION 1


#include<cstdlib>
void fun(double *x, double *y);
int main()
{
  double *x = NULL;
  double *y = NULL;

  x =(double*) malloc(5*sizeof(double));
#if DIMENSION == 2
  y =(double*) malloc(5*sizeof(double));
#endif

  fun(x,y);

  free(x);
#if DIMENSION == 2
  free(y);
#endif
  return 0;
}

void fun(double *x, double *y)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      x[i] = i;
#if DIMENSION == 2
      y[i] = i;
#endif
  }

}
```

Comment: Your solution works to suppress those errors, but I still keep the UNUSED macro in certain applications. For example, if the scope of variable is local within the function, I keep the UNUSED approach. If a variable is passed to function, then I do assign it a NULL as you suggested. Just to illustrate further, let's assume their is another variable in main(), call it "double *yprime". If "yprime" is not passed into "fun", then I use "UNUSED(yprime);". But if I use "UNUSED(y);" it still gives an warning, thus I'm now using y=NULL; as you suggested.

Comment: In the end, is assigning a variable to NULL the same as typecasting it to void as the UNUSED macro seems to do?

Comment: My previous comment should have read, "suppress those WARNINGS" not errors. Missed my opportunity to edit.

Comment: Would you mind commenting on: "In the end, is assigning a variable to NULL the same as typecasting it to VOID as the UNUSED macro seems to do?" Why would one solution better than the other?

Comment: Would you please post the warnings you are talking about.

Comment: GCC complier warnings associated with -Wuninitialized and -Wmaybe-uninitialized

Comment: can you post the warning itself please.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is just to initialize y to NULL.  That allows you to get rid of all of the `UNUSED` nonsense.

```
#define DIMENSION 1

void fun(double *x, double *y);

int main()
{
    double *x;
    double *y = NULL;

    x = calloc(5,sizeof(double));
#if DIMENSION == 2
    y = calloc(5,sizeof(double));
#endif

    fun(x,y);

    free(x);
#if DIMENSION == 2
    free(y);
#endif
    return 0;
}

void fun(double *x, double *y)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        x[i] = i;
#if DIMENSION == 2
        y[i] = i;
#endif
    }
}
```